# When I click on the button, it hides tables content, hoisting

Tags: javascript, php, html

Goal:

- I am trying to make all the table bodies hidden.
- When I click on the arrow button, the table body will be shown.

Issue:

- I can't hide the table bodies from the beginning.
- And only the last table hides his content when I click on the button.
  _ I am using a loop to create dynamic id that's why my function  get only the last id on the loop

Thank You.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dfirgo.css" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FRIGO</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        include("php/connexion.php");
        $rec = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM espace");
            echo" <div class=\"col\">";
        $i=0;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rec)) {
              $i++;
            echo"<table class=\"table\">
                <thead class=\"thead-dark\">
                <tr>
                    <th><img src=\"icones/neige.png\">ESPACE<button class='button12' value='tab".$i."' id='button12'onclick=\"myFunction()\"><img src=\"icones/élément1.png\"  align=\"right\"></button></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";
                       $_SESSION['case']='tab'.$i;echo"
                <tr id='tab".$i."'>
                    <td >";
                     echo $row[1]."-".$row[2]."-".$row[3]."-".$row[4];
                  echo  " </td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>";
        } echo"</div>";
       ?>
</div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var y = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['case']); ?>;
            var x = document.getElementById(y);
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
<script src="css/popper.min.js.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="css/slim.min.js.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="css/bootstrap.min.js.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So to understand, your problem is that you want to hide and show table bodies on click. Your listener is on your table header. There are several ways to do that. To go with your attempt just add a parameter to the onclick.

```
onclick="myFunction(this)"
```

Then you could just follow the hierarchy of your table to find your body element like this:

```
function myFunction(button) {
                       //th       //thead    //table    //tbody
        var x = button.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("tbody")
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

A different approach would be more understandable but I guess its fine. I also want to mention that toggling a class to the body would be better because then you don't have to worry about the initial display of the body which also could be flex or anything else. Something like...

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

 if (x.classList.contains("hide")) {
   x.classList.remove("hide")
 } else {
   x.classList.add("hide")
 }
```

Another approach:

define a data-attribute on the button which contains the id of the body and use document.getElementById ( / )

Comment: i am using a loop thas why i hade a promle that i can't fix the id

Comment: i need help with hoisting

Comment: @medbaha you could dynamically create the id... use a uuid function or an index (something like tbody_1). You can still just go with the example I gave you first.
What problem do you have with hoisting?

Comment: I did create a dynamic id on the loop but it only take the last id when I click on the button , I don't get the button id I only get the last id on the loop  , the hoisting can help me  with that problem but I don't know how to use it on my code